# Making buttons do different things in a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make a simple bootstrap based information fill out form, in which I wanted to make a button remove the "hidden" class from an element. I now want to add a second button that will remove the class of another hidden section.

This is the type of code that I was told would work: It does but I want to add another button that removes class from a section called "add more products".

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $("button").click(function(){
    $("#add_more_users").removeClass("hidden");

   });
  });
 </script>
<button id="button1">Add More:</button>
</div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-2">
  <div class="form-group">
    <h4>
      Product Container:
    </h4>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control">
      <option value="Container_1">
        Container 1
      </option>
      <option value="Container_2">
        Container 2
      </option>
      <option value="Container_3">
        Container 3
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see the "hidden" class in this code...

Comment: JAVA is NOT JavaScript

Comment: You do not have an element by the id of `add_more_users`.

Comment: so what is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you have the 2 elements that you want to show and 2 buttons that show them already. Something like:

```
<button id="button1">Add More Users:</button>
<button id="button2">Add More Products:</button>
<div id="add_more_users" class="hidden"></div>
<div id="add_more_products" class="hidden"></div>
```

To do this, use the correct selector.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#button1").click(function(){
  $("#add_more_users").removeClass("hidden");
 });
 $("#button2").click(function(){
  $("#add_more_products").removeClass("hidden");
 });
});
```

You might want to toggle show/hide the element. Use `toggleClass` instead of `removeClass` to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what your goal is based on the example but how about 
[something like this?](http://jsfiddle.net/mQH3p/)
When a user clicks the button - hidden element(s) will show.

**JavaScript:**

```
$('#button1').on('click', function(event){
   $('div.hidden').removeClass('hidden');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Java != JavaScript. JavaScript/jQuery is what you want to use.

Second, you are missing a vital piece of HTML - the element with an id of `add_more_users`.

Therefore, nobody can give you the code that would work for you. However, I can provide an example.

```
<input type="button" id="add_more_users_button" />
<input type="button" id="add_more_products" />

<div id="add_more_users" style="display: none;></div>
<div id="add_more_products" style="display: none;></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("add_more_users_button").click(function(){
     $("#add_more_users").css("display", "block");
   });

  $("add_more_products_button").click(function(){
    $("#add_more_products").css("display", "block");
  });
});
</script>
```

Try that. Instead of removing the `hidden` attribute, why not just modify the CSS? This will show the element on button click.

Comment: Updated my post a few times.